# Parallelizing a function that changes an attribute of a class under condition

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

How can I parallelize a function that modifies an attribute of a class? In the following example, `change_arr()` modifies the contents of the attribute `x` of the class based on `loc`; it assigns `-99` to each element of `x` that equals `loc`. When I run this script as written, I get the same array in both prints (and hence no modification took place). If I, however, comment the line using `Pool` and uncomment the two lines that do the same job using a for loop I get `[-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]` and `[-99, 2, -99, 0, -99, 2, -99]`, which is what I want.

My question is, then, how can I parallelize the use of the function `change_arr` to modify the same class attribute in parallel?

I am aware that there probably are better ways to implement this. However, the example is not exactly my code (as it is way longer and more complex), but a minimal example.

```py
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.x = np.array([-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3])

    def process(self):
        Pool(2).map(self.change_arr, [-3, -1, 1, 3])

        # for i in [-3, -1, 1, 3]:
        #     self.change_arr(i)

    def change_arr(self, loc):
        self.x[self.x == loc] = -99
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mc = MyClass()
    print(mc.x)
    mc.process()
    print(mc.x)
```

Comment: I'm not 100% confident, but `map(self.change_arr, [list])` will pass `list` to `self` and not to `loc`.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/how-to-use-multiprocessing-pool-map-with-multiple-arguments

Comment: there are 2 major issues here I see right away.. 1: separate processes don't share memory, so calling `Pool(2).map(self.change_arr...` must make a copy of `self` to send to the worker process and execute `change_arr` on that copy (the copy that exists in the main process is not modified). 2: you don't ever attempt to clean up the `Pool`. In this exact case, it should still function fine, but it's best to a context manager for the pool, or at least make sure to call `close()` on the pool when you're done with it, and call `join()` to make sure it stops properly.

Comment: @thethiny no, it won't, `self.change_arr` is a bound method, so the only parameter is `loc`

Answer (score 0):

You can share memory between processes with multiprocessing.Value and multiprocessing.Array types. I've created a minimal example how it works without involving numpy and classes.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Array

def change_arr(loc):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if loc == x[i]:
            x[i] = -99


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = Array('i', [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3])
    print([i for i in x])
    Pool(2).map(change_arr, [-3, -1, 1, 3])
    print([i for i in x])
```

I'm not sure if it works with numpy arrays. Theoretically the objects wrapped in Arrays or Values can be of any type.
The trick is to define x as a global variable and bind it to the function used in the map function.